# Run-time error '3061'. Too few parameters. Expected 3

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to use VBA to pull data from access into excel. I am able to use this script for other query's, but when for this specific query, I get this parameter error. The break happens here:

`Set rs = A.CurrentDb().QueryDefs("Query1").OpenRecordset()`

```
Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim A As Object
Dim rs As Object

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set A = CreateObject("Access.Application")
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

A.Visible = True
A.OpenCurrentDatabase ("Y:\UW\B\201811.accdb")
A.DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Query1")

Set rs = A.CurrentDb().QueryDefs("Query1").OpenRecordset()

If Not rs.EOF Then
ws.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
End If

For iCols = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = rs.Fields(iCols).Name
Next
rs.Close

 Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Here is query1:

```
SELECT W.MED, W.RX, W.HSAHRA, W.ACR, W.ML, Sum(W.MBRS) AS             
SumOfMBRS, Sum(W.PREM) AS SumOfPREM, Sum(W.CLMSTAT) AS SumOfCLMSTAT
FROM W
WHERE (((W.[DATE]) Between [Enter Start Date:] And [Enter End Date:]) AND 
((W.[ST])=[Enter State:]))
GROUP BY W.MED, W.RX, W.HSAHRA, W.ACR, W.ML
ORDER BY W.MED, W.RX, W.HSAHRA, W.ACR, W.ML;
```

Also, how do i convert query1 into a sqlstring?

Comment: What kind of query is Query1? Can you use the [edit] link below the question to add the SQL behind the query? Or, if you use this query in Access, itself, does it prompt for information?

Comment: I've updated it to show query1. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do those other queries have popup input prompts?

Answer (score 2):

User should input criteria into controls on form then reference those controls as parameter inputs:

```
strSQL = "SELECT MED, RX, HSAHRA, ACR, ML, Sum(MBRS) AS SumOfMBRS, Sum(PREM) AS SumOfPREM, Sum(CLMSTAT) AS SumOfCLMSTAT
FROM W " & _
"WHERE [DATE] Between #" & Me.tbxStart & "# And #" & Me.tbxEnd & "# AND [ST]='" & Me.tbxState & "' " & _
"GROUP BY MED, RX, HSAHRA, ACR, ML " & _
"ORDER BY MED, RX, HSAHRA, ACR, ML;"
```

Or in your case, reference cells of worksheet. If you want to use popups for user input, will have to use InputBox() function.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So I created an inputbox function and it works for the ST field. However, I get a data mismatch type error when I do that for the dates. Below is an example of the code working with the anticipated dates I choose to use.

Comment: Here is my code below:
    "Select MED, RX, HSAHRA, ACR, ML, SUM(MBRS) AS    SUMOFMBRS, SUM(PREM) AS SUMOFPREM, SUM(CLMSTAT)AS      SUMOFCLMSTAT " & _
         "FROM WEST " & _
         "WHERE ST = '" & myInputBoxVariable & "' " & _
         "and DATE BETWEEN 201710 AND 201809 " & _
         "GROUP BY MED, RX, HSAHRA, ACR, ML " & _
         "ORDER BY MED, RX, HSAHRA, ACR, ML "